# How to make figure align with text?

Tags: floats

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{spr-astr-addons}
\usepackage{url}\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\RequirePackage{color}
\def\imagei{\centerline{\color[gray]{.75}\rule{\hsize}{4pc}}}%
\def\imageii{\centerline{\color[gray]{.75}\rule{4pc}{4pc}}}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumncaption}{\@dblarg\@twocolumncaption}
\def\@twocolumncaption[#1]#2{%
  \renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{%
    \par\vskip\abovecaptionskip\begingroup\small\rmfamily
    \splittopskip=0pt
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{
      \@arrayparboxrestore \let \\\@normalcr
      \hsize=.5\hsize \advance\hsize-1em
      \let\\\heading@cr
      \noindent ##1\ ##2\par% this line for aastex
    }%
    \vbadness=10000
    \setbox\z@=\vsplit\@tempboxa to .55\ht\@tempboxa
    \setbox\z@=\vtop{\hrule height 0pt \unvbox\z@}
    \setbox\tw@=\vtop{\hrule height 0pt \unvbox\@tempboxa}
    \noindent\box\z@\hfill\box\tw@\par
    \endgroup\vskip \belowcaptionskip
  }%
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{4ex}%
  \caption[#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
%%\shortauthors{Al-Hamzawi}

\begin{abstract}
\begin{description}
\item[PACS numbers] 04.50.Kd, 04.20.-q, 04.25.Nx
\end{description}
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Keywords}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}
\twocolumncaption{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate  a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Mauris  ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum
urna  fringilla.}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Starobinsky (2007)]{starobinsky2007disappearing} Starobinsky, Alexei A 2007, JETP Letters, 86, 157--163

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that figure appears in a new page. Is there a way to make the figure appear in the same page as the text?

Comment: You had some answers on that question before. So why do you delete it and start all over again?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum ,I didn't phrase my question correctly before and I didn't get any answers that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to add `[t]˙option to figure environment:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]% <-- added option
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}}

\twocolumncaption{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate  a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Mauris  ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum
urna  fringilla.}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

*Note:*
Instead of `subcaption` you should load `subfig` package (for sub figures you use `subfloat` environments). Also it is sufficient to load `color` package ones, second loading by`\RequirePackage{color}` is surplus.